# Creating a shortcut in launcher to run a terminal command with more than one parameter as argument

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, environment-variables, automator

How do you create a shortcut in launcher that lets you run a terminal command using more than one variable?

For example, how do you create a launcher shortcut that will prompt you for varA and varB in:

`runThis --i varA --o varB`

where varA and varB should default to the last entry if they are not explicitly stated